# JQuery Draggable contained to parent and a bit extra

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

The docs of draggable show we can use containment parent to constrain where elements can be dragged to. This appears that the draggable element is constrained to another element.

Is it possible to extend the parent by "a bit"? (I will explain in more detail).

When we confine to a parent, the draggable element must remain inside:

[image]

I'd like it to either do the above or at least remain in contact with the parent as per next screen shot

[image]

My effort (in fiddle above) is poor as it only shows how to use draggable.

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable({containment:"parent"});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/o459n6mx/)

Comment: *Is it possible to extend the parent by "a bit"?* Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your question is more like *how do I constrain the draggable as shown above*. The answer would be to use an alternate element or by Array.

> **containment** Type: `Selector` or `Element` or `String` or `Array`
>
> Constrains dragging to within the bounds of the specified element or region.
>   Multiple types supported:
>
> - **Selector:** The draggable element will be contained to the bounding box of the first element found by the selector. If no element is found, no containment will be set.
> - **Element:** The draggable element will be contained to the bounding box of this element.
> - **String:** Possible values: `"parent"`, `"document"`, `"window"`.
> - **Array:** An array defining a bounding box in the form `[ x1, y1, x2, y2 ]`.

So before we initialize the Draggable, we can build our array of points relative to a target object and the item being dragged. You can gather these using `.position()`, `.width()`, and `.height()` or make them up as you need.

```js
$(function() {
  function makeOffsetArray(tObj, offsetX, offsetY) {
    var p = tObj.position();
    p.right = p.left + tObj.width();
    p.bottom = p.top + tObj.height();
    return [
      p.left - offsetX,
      p.top - offsetY,
      p.right,
      p.bottom
    ];
  }
  var pArr = makeOffsetArray($("#draggable").parent(), $("#draggable").width(), $("#draggable").height());
  console.log("Position Array:", pArr);
  $("#draggable").draggable({
    containment: pArr
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 30px;
}

#outerDiv {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

#draggable {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="outerDiv">
  <div id="draggable">
  </div>
</div>
```

The intersection appears to be the `top`, `left` of the draggable, so `bottom` and `right` do not need to be offset.

**References**

- https://api.jquery.com/position/
- https://api.jquery.com/width/
- https://api.jquery.com/height/
- https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment